# Does MySQL calculate the same SUM twice?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's assume I have a query like this :

```
SELECT Sum(imp)                  AS totalimp, 
       Sum(money)                AS totalmoney, 
       ( Sum(money) / Sum(imp) ) AS result 
FROM   table 
GROUP  BY date
```

Does MySQL cache the two sums, or will the SUM(imp) and SUM(money) be calculated twice ?

If not, is there a way to avoid MySQL from recalculating the sum twice ?

Thank you !

Comment: They will be calculated once for each `date`... which you're missing in your `SELECT`.

Comment: Ok, then it's great if MySQL doesn't do the same SUM twice ! (About the missing date, this is actually a dummy request just to expose the issue)

Comment: [Here's a demo for you](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ca44c/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT @totalimp := Sum(imp) AS totalimp, 
       @totalmoney := Sum(money) AS totalmoney, 
       ( @totalmoney / @totalimp ) AS result 
FROM   table 
GROUP  BY date
```

Comment: I already tried this, but my result is always NULL with this method. It seems it is not a good thing to assign the variable and use it at the same time (from what I found)

Answer (score 0):

How About

```
SELECT @totalimp := x.totalimp, 
   @totalmoney := x.totalmoney, 
   @result := ( x.totalmoney / x.totalimp )
FROM   (SELECT Sum(imp) AS totalimp, 
           Sum(money) AS totalmoney
         FROM   table 
         GROUP  BY date ) x
```

Comment: Yes this would work ! (But I already have many subquery levels like this and I wanted to avoid adding one more ! ) But as MySQL doesn't recalculate the SUM two times, I can leave it like the request in my question :)